# How can I cause a timeout exception in a database?

Tags: sql, timeout

I need to test some ASP.NET code that handles timeout exceptions from a call to a MS-SQL database.

I'm able to reduce my CommandTimeout parameter on the connection, however this might cause errors before reaching my code.

Is there a simple way to cause the database to timeout 'on cue'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for sir is the [WAITFOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) command, database timeouts on queue whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Added a waitfor delay to the sql being called. Bit dissapointed I can't just raise an exception when a certain clasue is met in sql.

Answer (score 3):

Begin a transaction in a management studio SQL window, update the table, and don't commit it:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE table SET ...
```

This will lock any website attempt to read that table.

Comment: Really messy compared to using waitfor

Comment: nice.. i had never seen that before.  defn not something i've _needed_ before! :)

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm working with a shared database. Will try this next time i have my own local though.

Comment: I was just trying to get a timeout on an AZURE database by doing a full update of one column inside a tran (no commit or rollback) and had also set transaction isolation level to serializable. No could do... i suspect AZURE is allowing dirty reads (read uncommitted) by default. I am now looking for other solutions.

Ok.. our default isolation level is read committed snapshot..(which is the last version of the row).. basically allowing a query to read the last value of the updated record>
I ran "DBCC useroptions" to find out

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just throw the exception that you want in whatever try block you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

Write a procedure that loops for ever doing some complex task with each iteration...and if that is not enough further expand it by calling the stored procedure recursively!

Answer (score 0):

Ive cheaped this by unplugging my ethernet cable lol...

Answer (score 0):

Begin your test, then turn off your database server (sc stop "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" or something).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider replacing the DB connection with a [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), that could simplify your testing.

In this case, the mock would simply always signal a timeout.

Answer (score -1):

write down the procedure or Query which take more than 30 seconds to execute and 
call this from asp.net code.